# Python Discord Bot reproduce audio from youtube link

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, replit

I'm trying to make my discord bot reporoduce audio from a link

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
   #...code
```

but it seems that I need to have installed a program called FFmpeg, and the problem is that i'm running my bot on replit.com,(which aparently you can't install nothing but packages) is there a way that I can play youtube audio links wihout installing any app, or there is any solution that someone can tell me?

Comment: https://replit.com/talk/ask/Installing-FFmpeg/28721

Comment: This it what is says 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from FFmpeg import video
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FFmpeg'`

Comment: use normal server instead of `replit.it` - but check if it can read from YouTube because some servers may block access to external portla - to stop spammers/hackers/etc.

Comment: @furas I’ll check if it can read from YouTube. The problems is that I use replit to make it run all day, because I can’t pay for a server to stay 24x7 to just run a small proyect made for learing, that’s why I was asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in replit.com they solved the problem with not being able to install any program to solve this, they have created a template called Discordpy-Music-Boy

Here is the link: https://replit.com/@replit/Discordpy-Music-Bot#main.py

They removed the capacity to install FFmpeg because it was initially used for botting and spamming, so they removed the functionality, as this post explains:

https://replit.com/talk/ask/Installing-FFmpeg/28721

And theres is no need to install nothing since it solves the problem with the FFmpeg using another package called youtube_dl that resolve most of the problem, but it's not perfect as some commands don't work, but it works fine for a small project.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31662726)